# Add new test package to CTS and building

Tags: android

I already learned how to build the `CTS` and execute it.

Now, I want to know the process of the `CTS` working flow. Can anyone explain it or share experience about how you add your test package in `CTS` then build the new `CTS` to test your application?

I try to search for the information in google but find nothing. If anyone know how to do it. Please do me a favor, thanks a lot. I want to know is how to add my application and test program to the android source tree then build it the completed `CTS` tool.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your test source let's say `TestXXX.java` under the `cts` source code directory like the other test cases.

So it looks like:

`cts/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/TestXXX.java`

`cd` back to the `<android_root>` then:

```
make cts
```

After that, you can run your test code `TestXXX` like the other `cts` cases.

Here is an example [EncodeAndMuxTest.java](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt)